# Delete from a file

Tags: c++

If i have a customer record in a file how do i delete a customer record from that file if i have two customer name john doe but they have different phone numbers.Basically I want to know how to use the name and phone number to delete customer record from the file. Here is my code.

```
void deleteCustomerData() {
  string name, customerInfo, customerData;
  string email;
  string phoneNumber;
  string address;
  string deleteCustomer;

  int skip = 0;

  cout << "Enter the name of the Customer record you want to delete: " << endl;
  getline(cin, name);
  cout << "Enter the phone number of the Customer record you want to delete: " << endl;
  getline(cin, customerData);

  ifstream customerFile;
  ofstream tempFile;
  int tracker = 0;
  customerFile.open("customer.txt");
  tempFile.open("tempCustomer.txt");

  while (getline(customerFile, customerInfo)) {
    if ((customerInfo != name) && !(skip > 0)) {
      if ((customerInfo != "{" && customerInfo != "}")) {
        if (tracker == 0) {
          tempFile << "{" << endl << "{" << endl;
        }
        tempFile << customerInfo << endl;

        tracker++;
        if (tracker == 4)
        {
          tempFile << "}" << endl << "}" << endl;
          tracker = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (skip == 0)
        skip = 3;
      else
        --skip;
    }
  }
  cout << "The record with the name " << name << " has been deleted " << endl;
  customerFile.close();
  tempFile.close();
  remove("customer.txt");
  rename("tempCustomer.txt", "customer.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a customer record is a line in your file, you need to:

1. Allocate memory to read in the file.
2. Read the file into memory.
3. Modify the memory.
4. Overwrite the file with the modified contents.
5. Free the memory you allocated.

Comment: `std::string`'s are all of variable length. So you cannot really allocate the necessary memory reasonably beforehand. I'd prefer a solution reading all lines into a `std::vector<std::string>` find the line to erase there, erase it from the vector and write it back to the file.

Comment: It s working ok until i have to delete two customer with the same name

Answer (score 0):

I do not know OP's file format so I have to work in generalities.

Define a customer structure

```
struct customer
{
    string name;
    string email;
    string phoneNumber;
    string address;
};
```

Write function to read in a customer or return false if it cannot. Probably easiest if you overload the `>>` operator with a function that looks like:

```
std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & in, customer & incust)
```

Write function to write out a customer or return false if it cannot. Again, easiest if you overload the `<<` operator.

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const customer & outcust)
```

Using the stream operators allows you to take advantage of the stream's boolean operator to tell whether or not the read or write succeeded.

Then use the read and write function to implement the following:

```
while read in a complete customer from input file
    if customer.name != deletename or customer.phoneNumber!= deletenumber 
        Write customer to output file
```

In English: As long as I can read a customer from the input file, I will write the customer to the output file if they are not the customer I wish to delete.

With the overloaded stream operators, this could be as simple as

```
customer cust;
while (infile >> cust)
{
    if (cust.name != deletename || cust.phoneNumber != deletenumber)
    {
        outfile << cust;
    }
}
```

All of the "brains" are in the read and write functions and the selection logic is dead simple. The customer either matches and is not written to file or does not match and is written to file.

All of the read and write logic is separated from the selection logic and can easily be reused for multiple different types of searches.

But you might find some benefit in caching, reading in once and building a `std::vector` of `customer`s to operate on without having to continually read and rewrite the file.

Comment: I'm new I don't understand anything above.

Comment: The big take-aways are 1. Store the customers in a structure. It's much easier to deal with data that comes in nice, well defined packages. 2. Make a read function and a write function that read or write exactly one customer at a time. You can independently test and perfect the read and write functions without having to worry about bugs in the rest of the code getting in the way. Then you can write the rest of your program based on the read and write functions and not have to worry about bugs in the read and write. This leads to 3. Separate the application logic from the utility logic.